# bigdecimal as parameter

Tags: java, jsp, ireport

I've got a problem regarding ireport again.

How can I pass parameter from jsp page to ireport? my field in ireport is bigdecimal. There is no bigdecimal datatype in jsp, right? I try to pass string and int value, and it shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

As JSP has access to everything in Java, it *does* have access to `BigDecimal`.

To convert a `String` to `BigDecimal` simply use [this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="fieldname" property="propname" 
                 value="<%= new BigDecimal(amount)%>" />
```